# How to make a hexagon in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I want to make a PCB that is hexagonal and has a it's sides of 51 mm. I've tried inserting a `.svg` file into Eagle but it didn't work, I've also tried using the polygon tool but I don't know how to make the sides a specific size.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: [There is an ULP for this.](http://eagle.autodesk.com/eagle/ulp?utf8=✓&q%5Btitle_or_author_or_description_cont%5D=hexagon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not really a way to do this easily, especially since EAGLE does not know something like shapes.

The simplest approach is to first calculate the coordinates of the edges:

$$x_i=51\cdot\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\cdot\alpha_i\right)$$
$$y_i=51\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\cdot\alpha_i\right)$$

with \$\alpha_i=0;60;120;...;360\$

and then write this lines to a file with extension `*.scr`:

```
CHANGE LAYER 20;
GRID MM;
SET WIRE_BEND 2;
WIRE 0 (51.000 0.000) (25.500 44.167) (-25.500 44.167) (-51.000 0.000) (-25.500 -44.167) (25.500 -44.167) (51.000 0.000);
```

`Layer 20` is the dimension layer. The PCB manufacturer will cut the PCB along the lines drawn there. `WIRE_BEND` defines how EAGLE connects two points. You want a single, straight line here. And the single 0 of the `WIRE`-command is the line width.

The file can then be executet by *File > run script...*

You can also paste this line into the text field just above the layout dawing area.

[image]

**Note:** To move the hexagon, you first have to select all six lines. If you already have some components on your layout, add an offset to the coordinates, so the hexagon is drawn in some distance. You can then select all lines easily and move them to where you want.

Comment: You can also do this into a library of shapes which makes it easier to move around once you are done :)

Comment: It works perfectly. This is going to be a DIY PCB because I can't wait weeks until a manufacture makes my PCB. Thank you!=)

Comment: How can I select the spacing between the traces? I want to put 5 traces inside the the spacing between two 2512 resistor pads and I can put only 3 :(

Comment: You can adjust the grid size where you set the unit, i.e. the first symbol in the row with "20 Dimension" in my screenshot.

Comment: I know it's late, but how could I make a 10mm hole in the center of the hexagon? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following on [sweber](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/57828/sweber)'s answer, here's a Python program to calculate the coordinates of the hexagon vertices:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from math import pi, sin, cos

angles = [n*2*pi/6 for n in range(0, 6)]

def hexagon_coords(theta, r):
    digits = 6
    x = round(r * cos(theta), digits)
    y = round(r * sin(theta), digits)
    return (x, y)

radius = 3.2

for angle in angles:
    coords = hexagon_coords(angle, radius)
    print(coords)
```

Comment: Eagle talks ULP, not python. But it can be converted, I guess.